# Filter XML results with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Long story short I'm trying to filter my XML code to only show bpcourses with the node bprint = Building Your Team . Here is an example of my XML:

```
<bpcourse>
<course>
<![CDATA[Introduction to Building Your Team]]>
</course>
<delivery><![CDATA[Virtual Class]]></delivery>
<link>
<![CDATA[http://#]]>
</link>
<linkTitle>
<![CDATA[FGH567900]]>
</linkTitle>
<duration>
<![CDATA[1 hr 10 min]]>
</duration>
<bprint>
<![CDATA[Building Your Team]]>
</bprint>
</bpcourse>
```

Here is a section of the code that keeps breaking:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("bpcourse");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
var bprint = $(x).find("bprint").text();
if (bprint == "Building Your Team")
{
```

I know my XML is correct, because I can view all the XML data with the first three lines of my code. I just can't figure out lines 3&4 for only showing bprint = Building Your Team.  Any assistance is much appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 4 of your JQuery will only be executed if the text within your `bprint` element has just the text `"Building Your Team"` , not if the element includes other text. So a regular expression might more along the lines of what you are looking for.  This is untested so it might need some fine-tuning, but it should suit your need.

```
var bprint = $(x).find("bprint").text();
if (bprint.indexOf("Building Your Team") >= 0) {
    // your code here
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a regular expression to `search` or `match` the `bprint` text for the string.

```
if (bprint.search('Building Your Team')) {
    // your code here
}
```

Also, in regards to traversing your XML, if you are using JQuery 1.5 and above, you can use the `$.parseXML()` feature. Here is a link to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) for it.